# PHP: change order of object properties

Tags: php, object-properties

Regarding PHP, is there a way to change the order of object properties?

```
class o {public $a = 1, $b = 2;}
$o = new o;
foreach (get_object_vars($o) as $k => $v) {
  print $k . '->' . $v . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
a->1
b->2
```

Existing public variables can be `unset()`, and added e.g. with `$o->c = 3;`. But [array functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) do not work with objects, and I do not want to convert the object to some stdClass.

The only practical workaround I can think of is to decorate an array object and overload the magic `__get()` and `__set()` methods, but that is just a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: i had posted a solution using `__invoke`  but someone downvoted, Dont you want to do it like that.

Comment: __invoke is not supposed to be used for this purpose

Comment: please check my answer - i edited it and added mention about ArrayObject interface

Comment: Maybe please be more specific about what you want to achieve. Why are you trying to use object as array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own way to iterate over object just by implementing [Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). By implementing methods next and current you define how to get current element and how to get the next one (but you will have to implement all methods).

For iteration use

```
foreach ($o as $k => $v) {
  print $k . '->' . $v . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Care to see some example? Did you understand it from link above?

On the other hand if you want to use your object as array, check [ArrayObject interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) or for simplier use [ArrayAccess interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)

Comment: By implementing the Iterator interface I technically do not have to use a decorator pattern. But.. to keep track of the information I would have to use an array. While the properties have their own order, which I want to be able to control.

Comment: You just need one variable in which you define the order you would like to proceed ($attributeOrder). Then in the next() method you traverse over this array instead and in the current() method return the value of desired attribute (respecting the $attributeOrder). In key() method you define the returned key (again from $attributeOrder)

Comment: First comment on the ArrayObject interface: "ArrayObject is not an array so you can't use the built in array functions". ArrayAccess is part of ArrayObject, which makes me wonder how to control the actual order of the object properties. How would I insert `$o->ah = 1.5;` between properties `$a` and `$b`, without reverting to arrays?

Comment: It looks like changing the order of the properties [can not be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899978/add-property-to-stdclass-at-the-top-of-the-object-in-php). So there is no use case.. :-) Implementing the ArrayObject interface is the next best thing. Thanks!

Comment: Its really logical - object attributes are inner programming structure used for purposes of programming language. If you want any kind of printing/viewing or even ordered iteration over attributes, you should use some business layer (mapper, view, ...) to wrap it into.