# Order object properties based on values of an array

Tags: php

I have the following object:

```
'new_value' => 
    'name' => 'Teste',
    'key' => 'TESTE',
    'icon' => 'empty',
```

And the following array:

```
array(
   0 => 'name',
   1 => 'icon',
   2 => 'key',
)
```

However I would like to arrange the properties in the object based in the value of the array, so the result would be:

```
'new_value' => 
    'name' => 'Test',
    'icon' => 'empty',
    'key' => 'TEST',
```

How can I achieve this? I couldn't find anything on google related to this, only how to sort an array of objects.

Comment: Object doesn't have ordered properties as far as I know. Also, the first one of the code examples doesn't look like an object at all. Perhaps this question is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200772/php-change-order-of-object-properties

Comment: Assuming stdClass objects, the most you can do is create a new object with properties in the desired order, based on your array, and then add values from your old object into it. Object properties can't be reordered like array keys.

Comment: Iterate your sorting array and recreate the array/object from the original.

Comment: @MarkusAO That worked, could you please add an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @MathiasHillmann sure, I've fluffed it out into an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object properties can't be reordered like array keys. You will have to create a new blank object (assuming stdClass objects), and then add in the properties in the desired order. First, let's recreate the source object:

```
$old_obj = (object) [
    'name' => 'Teste',
    'key' => 'TESTE',
    'icon' => 'empty'
];
```

Then, here's your new order:

```
$new_order = [
   'name',
   'icon',
   'key'
];
```

Then, we create a new object and add the properties in the desired order:

```
$new_obj = new stdClass();

foreach($new_order as $prop) {
    $new_obj->$prop = $old_obj->$prop;
}
```

This results in:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["name"] · string(5) "Teste"
    ["icon"] · string(5) "empty"
    ["key"] · string(5) "TESTE"
}
```

If you need to do this often, turn the operation into a helper function:

```
function reorder_props(object $obj, array $order) {
    $new_obj = new stdClass();
    foreach($order as $prop) {
        $new_obj->$prop = $obj->$prop;
    }
    return $new_obj;
}
```

Another approach would be to create an associative array with the keys in the desired order, and then cast it into a stdClass object (as we did in instantiating your source object). You could also use the above function/logic for reordering array keys with very minor modifications.